# setting default values with Play! Json Combinators

Tags: json, validation, scala, playframework

I'm using play!'s json combinators to validate, read and write JSON. Is it possible to specify default values in reads or writes if they are not set?

validation of json is done like this (where json is a JsValue):

```
json.validate[Pricing]
```

My code is:

```
case class Pricing(
    _id: ObjectId = new ObjectId,
    description: String,
    timeUnit: TimeUnit.Value,
    amount: Double = 0.0) {
        @Persist val _version = 1
}
```

my reads and writes:

```
implicit val pricingReads: Reads[Pricing] = (
    (__ \ "_id").read[ObjectId] and
    (__ \ "description").read[String] and
    (__ \ "timeUnit").read[TimeUnit.Value] and
    (__ \ "amount").read[Double]
)(Pricing.apply _)

implicit val pricingWrites: Writes[Pricing] = (
    (__ \ "_id").write[ObjectId] and
    (__ \ "description").write[String] and
    (__ \ "timeUnit").write[TimeUnit.Value] and
    (__ \ "amount").write[Double]
)(unlift(Pricing.unapply))
```

so if I would recieve a Json like:

```
{"description": "some text", "timeUnit": "MONTH"}
```

I get errors, that fields `_id` and `amount` are missing. Is there any possiblity to set the default values without adding it directy to the JsValue?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

I'd rather use `Option`s:

```
case class Pricing(
    _id: Option[ObjectId],
    description: String,
    timeUnit: TimeUnit.Value,
    amount: Option[Double]) {
      @Persist val _version = 1
    }
```

and replace your `pricingReads` with this:

```
implicit val pricingReads: Reads[Pricing] = (
  (__ \ "_id").readNullable[ObjectId] and
  (__ \ "description").read[String] and
  (__ \ "timeUnit").read[TimeUnit.Value] and
  (__ \ "amount").readNullable[Double]
)(Pricing.apply _)
```

Then your code will work on missing fields and yo will be able to do this:

```
_id.getOrElse(new ObjectId)
```

Comment: that's a good point using `Option`. but unfortunately it's not working with `ObjectId` (I'm using play-salat as ORM). anyway it works for other fields...